# why does my same zipcode plot rerun no longer run in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, plot

I just tested this code and it worked fine, only for me to change my plot to a bar chart and then after rerunning the file, it's showing me value error. I initially ran it multiple times because I was trying to set the x-axis to have the zipcodes in steps of 5 and now it does not run anymore. Now I have gone back to just plot to test but it still does not run. I do not understand what could have changed. The error says: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (55,) and (22,). What does this mean?

```
myzip = [60601, 60602, 60603, 60604, 60605, 60606, 60607, 60608, 60609, 60610, 60611, 60612, 60613, 60614, 60615, 60616, 60617, 60618, 60619, 60620, 60621, 60622, 60623, 60624, 60625, 60626, 60628, 60629, 60630, 60631, 60632, 60634, 60636, 60637, 60638, 60639, 60640, 60641, 60643, 60644, 60645, 60646, 60647, 60649, 60651, 60652, 60653, 60654, 60655, 60656, 60657, 60659, 60660, 60661, 60707]
frq = [6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 7, 1, 12, 10, 6, 6, 4, 6, 9, 4, 3, 11, 13, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 8, 7, 8, 3, 6, 8, 1, 2, 4, 12, 8, 5, 7, 1, 1, 1, 11, 5, 2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 2, 11, 5, 3, 3, 2]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close()
plt.plot(myzip,frq,'bo',Label='clinics in each zipcode', color='purple')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('zipcodes')
plt.ylabel('Number of clinics')
plt.title('Clinics per zipcode in Chicago')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to re-initialize (even reboot?) as I can see your plot just fine

Comment: Thank you @vav I called the dataset from a database. I must have lost the connection, just reran it and it worked! Is there a way to let it show more zipcodes when plotting a bar chart? I tried np.arange(60601,60708,5) but I got the error: 'shape mismatch, objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape'

Comment: just keep an eye that len(myzip)==len(frq). your arange is 22 elements, how many elements in second set?

Comment: its 22 as well cos the frequency was counted from the clinics zipcodes